# Search in dict for a tuple as a key with unknown part

Tags: python, dictionary, search, tuples

I know that my problem can be solved using simple iteration, but I'm new to python and wonder if there is an 'idiomatic' or standard language construction solution.

So the problem is that I have dictionary like this:

```
mydict = {
(1,2) : 111,
(2,3) : 222,
(xxx, yyy) : zzz,
(xxx, qqq) : www,
....
```

It is a dictionary which consist of key-tuples pointing to values
How do I search for tuple like `(xxx, *)` if I need only `(xxx, yyy)` and `(xxx, qqq)` pairs?
Is there any construction for `mydict[(xxx, *)]` or something similar?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could use a list comprehension: `[k for k in mydict if k[0] == xxx]`.

Comment: There's no way to do it without iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a direct language construct for that. You'll have to use a use a list comprehension selecting keys (or values) where the first element of the 2-tuple `(x, y)` is `x`:

```
lst = [v for (k1, _), v in mydict.items() if k1 == x]
```

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what i looked for!

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by breaking it down a step further and grouping all xxx, ??? together in the same level in the dictionary, instead of your tuple approach for the keys.

```
mydict = {
1: {2 : 111},
2: {3 : 222},
xxx { yyy : zzz,
      qqq : www},
....
```

This kind of gets you to the same spot that you want to be at because `mydict[xxx] = { yyy : zzz, qqq : www}`, which you can take a step further and do `mydict[xxx].values()` to get you an array `mydict[xxx].values = [zzz, www]`, an array of the values that contain `xxx` in the key.